# decodeObjectOfClasses is returning nil. Why?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Create a dictionary to be archived
        NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key1": @"value1", @"key2": @(42)};
        
        // Archive the dictionary to a data object
        NSError *archiveError = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict requiringSecureCoding:NO error:&archiveError];
        if (archiveError) {
            NSLog(@"Error archiving data: %@", archiveError);
            return 1;
        }
        
        // Unarchive the data object to a dictionary
        NSError *unarchiveError = nil;
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData:data error:&unarchiveError];
        if (unarchiveError) {
            NSLog(@"Error creating unarchiver: %@", unarchiveError);
            return 1;
        }
        NSString *unarchivedDict = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClasses:[NSSet setWithObjects:[NSDictionary class], [NSString class], [NSNumber class], nil] forKey:@"key1"];
        if (!unarchivedDict) {
            NSLog(@"Error decoding object: %@", [unarchiver error]);
            return 1;
        }
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];
        
        // Print the unarchived dictionary
        NSLog(@"%@", unarchivedDict);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But unarchivedDict is returning nil. Why isn't returning value1? Do I have to use decodeObjectForKey?

I know you can use forKey:@"root" to get the whole dict, but what other values can you use in forKey:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ***decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:*** is being called with ***key1***

However, it's the key in the dictionary that is being archived, not the key for the root object which is why it doesn't work.

You can try this:

```
NSDictionary *unarchivedDict = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClasses:[NSSet setWithObjects:[NSDictionary class], [NSString class], [NSNumber class], nil] forKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
if (!unarchivedDict) {
    NSLog(@"Error decoding object: %@", [unarchiver error]);
    return 1;
}
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

I change

```
forKey:@"key1"
```

to

```
forKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey
```

By doing this, the unarchiver will decode the root object of the archive.

You should get this

```
key1 = value1;
key2 = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys used in archiving/unarchiving represent entire objects in the archive. You need to unarchive the whole dictionary since you archived a whole dictionary. Once you have the dictionary, you can then access values like you would any other dictionary. In other words, what you are trying to do can't be done. You are sort of mixing unarchiving and key-value coding which makes no sense.

Also note that you did not use any keys when archiving so you have no keys to use when unarchiving. You need to use:

```
+ (id)unarchivedObjectOfClasses:(NSSet<Class> *)classes 
                       fromData:(NSData *)data 
                          error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

to unarchive the dictionary since you used `archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:` to archive it.

---

Apple really wants everyone to use secure coding. So passing `NO` when archiving is frowned upon. Pretty much all of the non-secure unarchiving methods are deprecated.